# Неправильно выводит динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

КОД ниже (C++)

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    int *mas, n;

    cout<<"Input n -> "; cin>>n;

    if (n >= 1) {
        mas = new int[n, n];
    }else return 0;

    cout<<"Input mas["<<n<<", "<<n<<"] -> \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout<<"mas["<<i<<", "<<j<<"] -> ";
            cin>>mas[i ,j]; 
        }
    }

    cout<<"\n\nOutput mas ->"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout<<"\nmas["<<i<<", "<<j<<"] -> ";
            cout<<mas[i ,j]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы путаете C#  и С++. И под двумерный массив память выделяется так: `int  **mas = new int *[n]; for (int i = 0;  i < n; i++){mas [i ] = new int;}`

Comment: ШТА? Как это путаю?

Comment: двумерный массив должен выглядеть так `mas[i][j]`  i - строки, j - столбцы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
mas = new int[n, n];
              ^^^^
```

используется оператор запятая. Это предложение эквивалентно следующему

```
mas = new int[n];
              ^^
```

Вам скорей всего нужно распределить массив массивов, чтобы моделировать поведение двумерного массива. Например

```
int **mas, n;
^^^^^^^^

//...

mas = new int *[n];
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    mas[i] = new int[n];
}
```

После использования массивов освободить занимаемую ими память следует в обратном порядке.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) delete [] mas[i];
delete [] mas;
```

Comment: может это тянет на следующий вопрос, но все же, можете пояснить для чего в языке используется выражения типа `mas = new int[n, n];`, подобное встречал только в C#? Где можно почитать?

Comment: @СемёнШелухин Такое предложение в C++ не имеет смысла. В C++/CLI или C# это соответствует созданию двумерного массива.